# Unable to get record from GCP DataStore when following Google documentation

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to upsert a record in DataStore and retrieve it following Google's own [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity). Upsert works, but retrieval doesn't. Is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) outdated? What else could be wrong?

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Key path element must not be incomplete: [Task: ]

Upsert:

```js
import { Datastore } from '@google-cloud/datastore'

const datastore = new Datastore()

const taskKey = datastore.key('Task');
const task = {
  category: 'Personal',
  done: false,
  priority: 4,
  description: 'Learn Cloud Datastore',
};

const entity = {
  key: taskKey,
  data: task,
};

await datastore.upsert(entity);
// Task inserted successfully.
```

Get:

```js
import { Datastore } from '@google-cloud/datastore'

const datastore = new Datastore()

const taskKey = datastore.key('Task'); // error occurs here
const [entity] = await datastore.get(taskKey);

console.log(entity);
```

Comment: The `upsert` must be returning a numeric ID something like `5700648512560`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datastore.key('Task');` statement generates a random ID that you can check by logging the response of `upsert()` method. You must specify that ID when retrieving data as shown below:

```
const taskKey = datastore.key(['Task', 12345]); // <-- array here

await datastore.upsert(entity);
```

Similarly, you can fetch data by specifying the ID:

```
const data = await datastore.get(datastore.key(["Task", 12345]))
```

Replace the ID with your custom ID or the one returned by `upsert()`. Check the Datastore console for more information.

Comment: I was close to this.. Thanks for pulling me over the finish line.